# Symlink error when using cdk command line tool or importing aws_cdk python module

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, node-modules, aws-cdk

I'm following the Getting Started with AWS CDK guide on AWS's website and attempting to create a python project on windows. I am getting a permissions error when trying to run the 'cdk synth' or 'cdk list' commands.

This is part of the error:

```
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError: 
  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\AWS\jsii\package-cache\@aws-cdk\asset-awscli-v1\2.2.200\76266c6c0354cd41d9860597faeaa631e6962e0fe67b1ec94555b06402098446' -> 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-kernel-XjYV2H\node_modules\@aws-cdk\asset-awscli-v1'
```

To add to my confusion, the `AWS\jsii\package-cache\...` is recreated event if I manually delete it whenever I run 'cdk synth' or 'cdk list'. And it is not the location I expected any packages/modules to be located in as I am using virtualenv.

Steps I have taken:

- Installed node v18.16.0
- Installed python 3.10.11
- installed aws-cdk package via `npm install -g aws-cdk`
- in an empty folder created a new cdk project via `cdk init sample-app --language=python`
- Started the virtual environment via `source .venv/Scripts/activate`
- installed python modules via `pip install -r requirments.txt`
- Ran `cdk --version` which returns version information as expected
- Ran `cdk synth` or `cdk list` which returns the error

I have also tried running python from the command line and running the command `import aws_cdk` and that returns the same error as trying to run `cdk synth` or `cdk list`. Running the commands with admin privileges does resolve the issue, but none of the documentation indicates needing admin privileges to use the cdk tool, so I believe I am missing a step or have made a mistake somewhere. This is also for a work machine so I will not be able to use admin privileges every time I need to use the tool.

**EDIT:** I seem to have resolved the issue. After starting the virtual environment, I ran the command `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` instead of `pip install -r requirements.txt`. The docs do mention using the first command but I'm not sure why this would make a difference. Both pip and the python executable are in the virtual environment. Regardless, issue is not fixed and I can use the tool as expected.